# Pass data to view through Accessibility service – Android

Tags: java, android, accessibility, accessibilityservice, accessibility-api

I want to change text inside EditText within Accessibility service.
My code is:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    final AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
if (source != null & event.getClassName().equals("android.widget.EditText")) {
       AccessibilityNodeInfo currentSource = source;

        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "TestData");
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        currentSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
```

And it works well. When user presses on EditText it changes to "TestData". After that shows dialog with button. And I want to change text through pressing the button.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setTitle("Test dialog");
        builder.setMessage("Content");
        builder.setPositiveButton("User", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Test Username");
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                currentSource.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Clipboard refreshes if press the button, but text inside EditText doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolve my problem with timer thread. It helped me, because Accessibility service works on different devices with some "delay".

Comment: can u throw some light how to read ussd with accseibility service

Comment: @SrishtiRoy sorry, I haven't worked with ussd and accessibility service.